# Search and replace in MySQL - numeric values [on Wordpress]

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

UPDATE 1: I have PHPMyAdmin installed on my server.

---

I have a live Wordpress setup that has more than 5k comments.

**Database Name:** fhfh_wpdb535

**Table Name:** kevi_comments

**Column Name under "kevi_comments" table:** comment_content

Thousand of comments content have a lot of numeric value that look something like:

**USECASE 1**

93648847498442357831

936488/474/984423/578343

936488 / 474 / 984423 / 578343
4075936487

25/04/2016

648373

etc.

Now, how do I replace all these in numbers in bulk with asterisks (*).  So, after this, the above mentioned entries in the database will look something like these:

93648847498442357831 --->>>> ********************

**USECASE 2**
Similarly, there are email IDs too.. like abc@gmail.com. How do I replace them too with something like ***@******** or **************

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it directly using MySQL query, since you can't use directly REGEXP in combination with replace() function.

However, you should try using Search and Replace script for WordPress:

Download it from here: 
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

And extract its folder in main WordPress directory.

Check regex checkbox, add [0-9] in 'replace' text box, and asterisk in 'with' text box, 
Select comments table and include comments_content column only.

I suggest you to do first only dry run, and then live run

Comment: If i don't want to use it, can I use PHPMyAdmin for this? I already have it installed on my server.

Comment: @ravichopra, phpmyadmin is just a tool to administer your MySQL database. You could build a complex query, that consists of MySQL function that acts as preg_replace() , but Search and Replace script is a faster way to do. It has a really small footprint, and you can delete it after work is done by one click. When you copy it over your main WordPress directory, it recognizes wp-config.php and reads db params from it. So no need to setup manually that. After that, just follow my instructions :)